# Display/Track/Delete Mysql Rows via JSP pages

Tags: jsp, jdbc, mysql-workbench

Im having the following Problem:

I Have made a web application which runs on Apache Tomcat.

Im using a Mysql Database as backend database for my application. The application Simply provides a GUI for entering rows,updating and deleting them

The problem is this, that when I insert a new row in my database using the MySql Database Interface (by passing an sql query directly), I can manipulate the rows From my JSp Pages (delete,select,Update)

However If i enter a new row in the database By using a JSP Page (JDBC connection), The row does get entered ,however Im unable to delete/select/update any columns

No errors are displayed. So can anyone kindly point out why is this happening? and how to resolve this?

Thanks

```
Here is the code for the jdbc Connection I use to insert the row in the Mysql database.


<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@
 page import="java.sql.*"
 %>

<%

Connection connection = null;
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
%>
<html>
<head><link href="style.css" rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>

<body bgcolor="white" >

<div id="container">
<div id="header">
    <img src="logo.jpg">

  <div class ="horiztext"><p> Order Tracker</p></div>
  </div>

</div>
  <br>

    <img src="banner.jpg" width="1500 " height="5"><br>
    <% if(session.getAttribute("username") !=null)
 {
 %>
     <div id="navbar">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="newoder.jsp">New Order</a></li> 
        <li><a href="updateorder.jsp">Update Order</a></li> 
        <li><a href="trackorder.jsp">Track Order</a></li> 
        <li><a href="trackdelay.jsp">Track Delay</a></li> 
        <li><a href="vieworder.jsp">View Database</a></li>
        <li><a href="delete.jsp">Delete Order</a></li>  
        <li><a href="logout.jsp">Logout</a></li>
   </ul> 
  </div>   
  <br>
<%
 String SNo=request.getParameter("Sno");
 String ProductName=request.getParameter("ProductName");
 String ProductType=request.getParameter("ProductType");
 String Model=request.getParameter("Model");
 String Make=request.getParameter("Make");
 String LicenseVoucher=request.getParameter("LicenseVoucher");
 String Location=request.getParameter("Location");



 %>
 <br>
   <div align="center"><font size="6" color="black"> 
  <br>
 <%
 try
 {

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test","root"
,"root");
 st = connection.createStatement();

 String query="insert into inventory values
(' "+SNo+" ',' "+ProductName+" ','"+ProductType+" ',' "+Model+" ',' "+Make+" ','  
 "+LicenseVoucher+" ','        "+Location+" ')";
  st.execute(query);
   out.println("DATA INSERTED");


 }

  catch(Exception e)
 {
  out.println("DATA NOT INSERTED");
 }
%>
 </font></div>
 <%
 } 
else { %>
 you are not logged in click here to <a href="eric.jsp"><b>login</b></a>

 <%
} %> 

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use?

Comment: '... when I enter a new row ...' enter? Do you mean Insert or Select? 'The problem is ... i can manipulate ...' A common concept of WebApps is the manipulation of Datas, i do not see why this should be a problem! Anyway, i must be creative to understand you, can you told me if you use Transactions in any of your programs connected to the database (if the transaction is not committed, the data wont be changed)?

Comment: yes i updated my post with the code. I can maipulate the rows of mysql database from the web application (delete/update/select) if i insert the rows directly from the Mysql workbench

However if I insert the rows via the web application (using jdbc connection) in the Mysql Database, Im unable to generate views (via select) or delet/update the inserted rows from the web application



Kindly help :|
Howeve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used prepared statement for inserting... seems to solve the problem somehow :|

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I have found to manipulate SQL from JSP is to use the [tag library](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm):

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>


<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST"
     user="user_id"  password="mypassword"/>
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from Employees;
</sql:query>

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Age</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.first}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.last}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${row.age}"/></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>

<sql:update dataSource="${snapshot}" var="count">
   INSERT INTO Employees VALUES (104, 2, 'Nuha', 'Ali');
</sql:update>
```

Let me know how you get on...

Comment: thank you for your insight hd1, however I'm not proficient in tag library for now. Could you see the code I posted and suggest some solutions?

Comment: MySQL listens on port 3306, not 330, by default.

Comment: yes, however i changed it to 3307 purposefully. I dont think that would cause the problem.